# Turning a query result to an associative array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

In my php I am running a simple query which returns a resultset(0 or many) from the database I have.

Currently on the fronted the rersult looks like this :

```
name: Smoothie description: Banana Smothie name: Phad Thai description: Noodles with shrimps name: Noodles description: Noodles with noodles.
```

The string can also look like this, aka `name: Smoothie description: Banana Smothie` or with more entries, like in the  example above.

What I am aiming to have is an associative array from my result, which I can turn into json string and pass it to the frontend.

Unfortunately what i tried so far didn't work.

This is my php :

```
<?php
include_once 'db/dbconnect.php';
$input = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['data']));

for ($i=0; $i < count($input); $i++) {
  $stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT recipes.recipeName, recipes.recipeDescription FROM ingredients, recipes, recipesingredients WHERE recipes.recipeId = recipesingredients.recipeIdFK AND recipesingredients.ingredientIdFK = ingredients.IngredientId AND ingredients.ingredientName = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $input[$i]);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $stmt->bind_result($db_recipe_name, $db_recipe_description);

  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "name: ".$db_recipe_name." description: ".$db_recipe_description." ";
  }
}



 ?>
```

Can someone help me make the result from the query to an associative array with the current code i have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add each one to an array. Also, use modern JOIN syntax:

```
<?php
include_once 'db/dbconnect.php';
$input = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['data']));

for ($i=0; $i < count($input); $i++) {
    $stmt=$con->prepare("SELECT recipes.recipeName, 
        recipes.recipeDescription 
        FROM ingredients i
        JOIN recipesingredients ri
            ON ri.ingredientIdFK = i.IngredientId
        JOIN recipes r
            ON r.recipeId = ri.recipeIdFK
        WHERE i.ingredientName = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $input[$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($db_recipe_name, $db_recipe_description);

    $rslt = array();
    $rowno = 0;
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $rslt[$rowno] = array('name' => $db_recipe_name, 'description' => $db_recipe_description);
        $rowno++;
        echo "name: ".$db_recipe_name." description: ".$db_recipe_description." ";
    }
    $jsonRslt = json_encode($rslt);
    echo "<p>JSON Results:<pre>".$jsonRslt."</pre></p>\n";
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. i tried it and gives me this output :
 ["banana","rice noodles"]
main.js:12   
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pm/search.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />

Comment: Sorry, forgot the close() statement. If that doesn't fix it, let me know which line is 29.

Answer (score 0):

Just call fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) on $stmt. It returns a associative array of all results. No need to use a while loop.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchall-examples

```
include_once 'db/dbconnect.php';
$input = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['data']));
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT recipes.recipeName, recipes.recipeDescription FROM ingredients, recipes, recipesingredients WHERE recipes.recipeId = recipesingredients.recipeIdFK AND recipesingredients.ingredientIdFK = ingredients.IngredientId AND ingredients.ingredientName = ?");

for ($i=0; $i < count($input); $i++) {

  $stmt->bind_param("s", $input[$i]);
  $stmt->execute();

  $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i tried it and gives me this output : ["banana","rice noodles"] main.js:12 <br /> <b>Fatal error</b>: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pm/search.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />

Comment: @RobertRoss edited my answer, could you try the code that i added?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetch_assoc` method and save it into an array. Like

```
// In the beginning of your code initialize an ampty array
$result = array();
// Have your query here.
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $result[] = $row;
}
$stmt->close();
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. i tried it and gives me this output : ["banana","rice noodles"] main.js:12 <br /> <b>Fatal error</b>: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pm/search.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />